# ant command not found on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automation, ant, jenkins-plugins

15:05:54  + ant -version
15:05:54  /workspace/script.sh: line 1: ant: command not found

How can i resolve this? Since ant is installed and working well on the remote server but not running via jenkins, throwing this error.

trying to run ant builds through jenkins, but this error keeps coming

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following.

Add the ant executable to the PATH variable.

```
withEnv(["PATH+ANT_DIR=/PATH/TO/ANT/bin"]) {
    sh 'ant -version'
  }
```

or using the absolute path to ant executable

```
./path/to/ant/executable/ant -version
```